# How to tell FileWriter to close any files before making a new file in Java

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a buffered writer which is an instance of `FileWriter` in java. I have some functions which  work like this:

```
private void a() {
        try {
            fileMaker("A");
            bufferedWriter.write("x");
            b();
            bufferedWriter.write("z");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
private void b() {
        try {
            fileMaker("B");
            bufferedWriter.write("b");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

```
    private FileWriter bufferedWriter;
    private void fileMaker(String fileName) {
        try {
            bufferedWriter = new FileWriter("./artifact/" + fileName + ".txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("there is something wrong in classFileMaker");
        }
    }
```

So my problem is, somehow after returning from function `b` I get a exception and can't write to file "A". 
Any idea why?

Comment: Because you are using the same variable `bufferedWriter` for all open files, you need to have a unique FileWriter instance per opened file

Comment: I'm setting `bufferedWriter` again when I open a new file so the older one would be overwritten. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: And then you try to access the one that has been overwritten. Also, you should print any exception you get, either just the message or the whole stack trace. It helps with troubleshooting your program.

Comment: Yes. That was actually correct. Thanks. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileMaker` reuses the same `bufferedWriter` member, so every time you call it you lose the reference to the previous file's writer. A better design would be to return a new instance of a writer from the method and have the caller manage it:

```java
private static FileWriter fileMaker(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return new FileWriter("./artifact/" + fileName + ".txt");
}

private void a() {
    try (FileWriter bufferedWriter = fileMaker("A")) {
        bufferedWriter.write("x");
        b();
        bufferedWriter.write("z");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

private void b() {
    try (FileWriter bufferedWriter = fileMaker("B")) {
        bufferedWriter.write("b");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```